# IHostBuilder does not contain a definition for ConfigureWebHostDefaults

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to use the new `GenericHost` in **.NET Core 3.0** documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0) but I'm getting a really basic error that stats `IHostBuilder` does not contain a definition for the `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` function.

Looking at the **ASP.NET 3.0** documentation here for the `IHostBuilder` interface [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.0) I cant see any reference to `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` so I'm a bit confused.

I'm using the 3.0.0 packages for `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` but cant help but feel I'm either missing something really obvious or that `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` has for some reason been removed?

Update -- Screen shot of Program.cs

[image]

Update -- .csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: @Tim post your code, not images of your code. Images don't compile, they can't be copied and tested.

Comment: Yeah remote access isn't going to happen sorry @TanvirArjel.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can share the .csproj but its pretty much the template console application with the additional package references. Will add it to the question in any case as it might be useful

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Along with `using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`, `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` also require `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;` as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting; //<-- Here it is
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

Moreover it look like your project is a Console Application. That is the problem. `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` is for Web Application only. So you can convert your Console Application into Web Applicaton by replacing `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"` with `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"` in your `.csproj` file as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Yep completely overlooked that - I've updated it to use Sdk.Web and its picking up the ConfigureWebHostDefaults extension. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Tim Great to see that your problem has been solved. Welcome.

Comment: Thank you @TanvirArjel for the solution. 
It didn't mention anywhere in Microsoft's 3.0 migration documentation(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#hostbuilder-replaces-webhostbuilder) that both namespaces should be used together. Keyword (*.Hosting) in namespaces can miss lead anyone.

Comment: I want to start SignalR server along with my startup of WPF application. I have used this code. works perfectly fine. But I need to keep a empty web project in the solution so that ConfigureWebHostDefaults line does not throw exception. Any other option to make this line work and get rid of the web project.

Comment: Too bad, it still doesn't work. They've made a mess of it.

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with @TanvirArjel

For Last statement instead of changing `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"` with `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"`. We can keep `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk"` as it is, and add `FrameworkReference "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"` in `ItemGroup` example is as follow

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="3.1.16" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```