# IHostBuilder does not contain a definition for configurewebhostdefaults and no accessible extension method... etc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I really appreciate any help regarding this issue. I can't seem to find ConfigureWebHostDefaults method on IHostBuilder. I followed this answer exactly [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097568/ihostbuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-configurewebhostdefaults)

but I am not able to figure out why it's not working. I am targeting only net472 in my project and I have both

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
```

included and I have

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="5.0.0" />
```

installed and I have my project xml tag as the following

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

I can't target netcoreapp any version because my project depends on some external windows native libraries. the reason I am not using ASP.NET Framework is because I need to package my webapp as a standalone exe.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're trying to use an ASP.NET Core 3 method in an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application, which obviously won't work. Look at the "Applies to" section of [the documentation for `GenericHostBuilderExtensions.ConfigureWebHostDefaults`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.generichostbuilderextensions.configurewebhostdefaults?view=aspnetcore-3.0).

If you want to use that, you need to upgrade (notice that ASP.NET Core 2.2 is not even supported anymore) and you will have to stop using .NET Framework too.

Comment: okay so I missed the Applies to section. I really would like to upgrade but I can't as it's not my decision  I think I will refactor the code somehow to configure the web host some other way