# Call ConfigureWebHostDefaults when using Worker service template

Tags: .net-core

My question is regarding this documentation page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Which says:

> An app created from the Worker Service template specifies the Worker SDK in its project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">
```

The page then describes how to change the default pipeline config behavior:

> To change the default behavior, add the hosted service (VideosWatcher in the following example) after calling ConfigureWebHostDefaults:

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097568/ihostbuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-configurewebhostdefaults), answer says:

> Moreover it look like your project is a Console Application. That is the problem. ConfigureWebHostDefaults is for Web Application only. So you can convert your Console Application into Web Applicaton by replacing Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" with Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" in your .csproj file

The error I am getting is

> IHostBuilder does not contain a definition for `ConfigureWebHostDefaults`...

My specific question at this point is: Should I be able to use the worker service SDK as specified in the documentation and also call `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` as is also specified in the documentation?  If so, how do I do that?  I am referencing `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of cource you can, just install the [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/5.0.0) package

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions --version 5.0.0
```