# Why doesn’t IHostBuilder find the ConfigureWebHostDefaults method working with the Visual Studio’s Worker Service template?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-aks, background-service, worker-service

I created a .NET 5, Visual Studio project using the [Worker Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) template, which creates a `Program.cs` file containing the `Program` class with the following method:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
   {
      services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
   });
```

Since I want to specify a `Startup` class to implement health checks for this application (since it will be deployed to Kubernetes (I’m following [this tutorial](https://www.johanohlin.com/posts/2019-11-07-worker-service-in-kubernetes-with-health-checks/))), I read there’s the [ConfigureWebHostDefaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.generichostbuilderextensions.configurewebhostdefaults?view=aspnetcore-6.0) extension method. However, I get the following error trying to use it:

[image]

The code that gives me the error is the following (the one hidden by the error in the above screenshot):

```
.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); })
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472877/call-configurewebhostdefaults-when-using-worker-service-template) seemed to show my situation, but the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` package doesn’t resolve the issue. I also tried to import the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` packages, without success. I’m already using the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` package.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's still in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` namespace, but it's now in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` assembly.

(The class containing the method is GenericHostBuilderExtensions).

Comment: I tried importing that package, but the problem remains.