# Error CS1061: 'HostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication'

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I have just created a new Azure Functions project with a Queue Trigger, straight out of the box using the following tech stack, and it doesn't build, and returns an error stating that " Error CS1061: 'HostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication'".

**Tech Stack**

- Visual Studio for Mac (17.6.8).
- .Net 7.0
- Azure Functions v4

**Here is the code where the error occurs (straight out of the box Program.cs file)**

```html
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() //FAILING ON THIS LINE HERE!
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**Here is the QueueTrigger (straight out of the box):**

```html
using System;
using Azure.Storage.Queues.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AzureFunctionsDotNet7Example
{
    public class QueueTriggerFunctionExample
    {
        private readonly ILogger<QueueTriggerFunctionExample> _logger;

        public QueueTriggerFunctionExample(ILogger<QueueTriggerFunctionExample> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(QueueTriggerFunctionExample))]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "connection-string-goes-here")] QueueMessage message)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message.MessageText}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the .csproj file for the project, for reference:**

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I came across [this post here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097568/ihostbuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-configurewebhostdefaults), however this did not fix the issue (Installing NuGet Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting).

Any ideas on how to fix this? Help greatly appreciated. Many thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**
[Here is the repository on Github](https://github.com/sahgilbert/AzureFunctionsDotNet7Example)

**UPDATE 2:**
Following on from the answered provided by Pravallika KV, I added all of the required missing NuGet Packages, which did indeed fix the build, but the application now fails with the following error:

"Failed to load /Users/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio/azure-functions-cli/Releases/4.67.0/cli_arm64/libhostpolicy.dylib, error: dlopen(/Users/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio/azure-functions-cli/Releases/4.67.0/cli_arm64/libhostpolicy.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio/azure-functions-cli/Releases/4.67.0/cli_arm64/libhostpolicy.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio/azure-functions-cli/Releases/4.67.0/cli_arm64/libhostpolicy.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio/azure-functions-cli/Releases/4.67.0/cli_arm64/libhostpolicy.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
An error occurred while loading required library libhostpolicy.dylib from [/Users/Library/Application Support/VisualStudio/azure-functions-cli/Releases/4.67.0/cli_arm64/]"

Comment: Install these packages `Azure.Storage.Blobs`,`Azure.Storage.Files.Shares`,`Azure.Storage.Queues`,`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http`,`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore`,`Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues`,`Microsoft.Extensions.Azure`. Refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/aUR5Uhv.png).

Comment: Thanks, they've all worked except "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" which has an error - "Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: Try upgrading or downgrading `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions` package version.

Comment: It seems the project template on Visual Studio on Mac is missing Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore as a dependency. Adding this Nuget package resolved the error above.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to install the missing NuGet packages.**

- I have created a .NET 7 isolated Queue triggered Azure function.

**.Csproj:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.13.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.11.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage.Queues" Version="5.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Function.cs:**

```cs
using System;
using Azure.Storage.Queues.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 
public class Function
 {
     private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

     public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
     {
         _logger = logger;
     }

     [Function(nameof(Function))]
     public void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "demo")] QueueMessage message)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {message.MessageText}");
     }
 }
```

**Program.cs:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_connection_string>",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

**host.json:**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

**Console Output:**

```cs
[2024-02-07T15:43:01.514Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 28100) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-02-07T15:43:01.738Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: queueTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-07T15:43:07.583Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-02-07T15:43:08.845Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'myqueue-items'.', Id=8be1eaf6-f837-44d1-ae01-42777355955e)
[2024-02-07T15:43:08.853Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: e0a9f004-ab4d-4ae7-a01a-a0c4c6c0040f, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-02-07T15:43:08.000+00:00
[2024-02-07T15:43:09.233Z] C# Queue trigger function processed: Hello World
[2024-02-07T15:43:09.335Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=8be1eaf6-f837-44d1-ae01-42777355955e, Duration=656ms)
```

Comment: I'm now getting a different error. I've updated my question with the full error, thanks!

Comment: Check for updates in visual Studio and try rebuilding the project.

Comment: I'm running the latest version of everything, but I'm on a MacBook Pro with a silicon chip (although I believe this is now supported). Thanks for your help

Comment: In Visual Studio, `right click on your project=>select properties=>Build=>Select Platform Target` as **Any CPU** (or) **X86**. Refer [Image](https://i.imgur.com/Ku8MUrk.png).